# Regression With ARMA Errors - Cochrane Orcutt Procedure

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I am using the `Cochrane.orcutt` procedure to do a time series analysis.

I did the initial regression with the `lm` function, and then past the result to `Cochrane.orcutt`.

```
reg <- lm(data$Y ~ data$Y_Lag1 + data$X1 + data$X2)

regfinal <- cochrane.orcutt(reg)
regfinal
Cochrane.Orcutt

Call:
lm(formula = YB ~ XB - 1)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.72984 -0.32750  0.03553  0.17989  0.69595 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
XB(Intercept)                0.39347    0.09500   4.142  0.00252 ** 
XBdata$Y_Lag1                1.05427    0.09556  11.033 1.57e-06 ***
XBdata$X1                   -3.16739    0.80754  -3.922  0.00350 ** 
XBdata$X2                   -3.30504    0.86569  -3.818  0.00410 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.447 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9451,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9208 
F-statistic: 38.76 on 4 and 9 DF,  p-value: 1.115e-05


$rho
[1] -0.6855955

$number.interaction
[1] 8
```

---

I am doing a time series with regressors.

```
Y_t = a + b*Y_t-1 +c*X1_t +d*X2_t
```

I just have a few questions.

1. This Cochrane procedure looks like it gives back a list, not a lm. I want to plot the fitted vs actuals, and also use the predict function. The code below gives an error (whereas it works on stuff from "lm")

   ```
   plot(data$Y,col="red")
       lines(data$Y)
   lines(fitted(regfinal),col="blue")
   ```
2. Is what I am doing with the regression correct for a theory point of view? That is, including in the lagged value of the response? I am new to Regression with ARMA errors. I have seen somewhere that you are supposed to run the standard regression with only the predictors (no Y_Lag1), and then you get the residuals and you build a model with it. The problem is, when I exclude Y_Lag1 from my lm, the significance of everything else drops away:

```
Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
XB(Intercept)               -0.02025    0.73246  -0.028    0.978
XBdata$X1                   -1.31001    0.98394  -1.331    0.213
XBdata$X2                   -1.32077    1.42550  -0.927    0.376

Residual standard error: 0.8196 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2635,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.04256 
F-statistic: 1.193 on 3 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.3616


$rho
[1] 0.6886191

$number.interaction
[1] 6
```

Comment: This should stay open, IMO. Questions solely about how software works are off topic here, but "Is what I am doing with the regression correct for a theory point of view?" is certainly on topic here.